# Sobre renderização de botão

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml

Olá, pessoal. Estou montando um programa que trabalha com cadastro de usuários. Neste projeto existe uma tela para consultar os usuários cadastrados. O problema é o seguinte: na tela de pesquisa de cadastros, existe um campo para se preencher o nome do usuário a ser pesquisado e um SelectOneRadio para selecionar o status do usuário(ativo, inativo e todos).

Por exemplo, se no campo de pesquisa digitar "Bruno" e escolher a opção "Ativo" no SelectOneRadio e realizar a pesquisa, a pesquisa retornará todos os Brunos com o cadastro em estado "Ativo". Em cada cadastro existe um botão "Editar" que abre uma tela para se alterar o cadastro.

A questão é que eu gostaria de usar a propriedade "rendered" no componente p:button do xhtml para que quando a pesquisa for realizada com a opção "Todos" do SelectOneRadio selecionada, o botão "Editar" NÃO SEJA RENDERIZADO. Eu consegui desabilitar e habilitar o botão "Editar" conforme o cadastro dos usuários retornados pela pesquisa, mas o problema desta vez é que agora não depende do cadastro do usuário retornado pela pesquisa e sim da ItemValue da opção selecionada em SelectOneRadio quando eu clico no botão "Pesquisar". Estou enviando o código dos meus arquivos relacionados à esta pesquisa.

**PesquisaUsuario.xhtml**

```
<ui:define name="titulo">Pesquisar Usuarios</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">
    <h:form id="frmPesquisa">
    <p:messages showDetail="false" showSummary="true" autoUpdate="true" />

    <h1>Pesquisa de usuários</h1>

    <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
        <p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:commandButton value="Pesquisar" action="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.pesquisar}" update="@form" />
            <p:selectOneRadio id="StatusUsuario" value="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.filtro.status}" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ativo" itemValue="Ativo" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Inativo" itemValue="Inativo" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Todos" itemValue="Todos" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
        <p:toolbarGroup align ="right">
            <p:button value="Novo" outcome="/usuarios/CadastroUsuario"/>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
    </p:toolbar>

    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
        <p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome"/>
        <p:inputText id="nome" size="60" maxlength="80"
        value="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.filtro.nome}"/>
    </p:panelGrid>

    <p:dataTable id="usuariosTable"
            value="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.usuariosFiltrados}" var="usuario"
            style="margin-top: 20px" emptyMessage="Nenhum usuario encontrado."
            rows="20" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
            paginatorPosition="bottom">

    <p:column headerText="Id" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Nome" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.nome}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="RG" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.rg}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="CPF" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.cpf}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Email" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.email}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Telefone" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.telefone}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Endereço" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.endereco}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Estado" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.estado}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="CEP" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.cep}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Status" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.status}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Operações" style="width: 100px; text-align: center">
    <c:set var ="status" scope = "session"/>
            <p:button outcome = "/usuarios/CadastroUsuario" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Editar" disabled="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.inativo}">
                <f:param name="usuario" value="#{usuario.id}" />
            </p:button>
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-bloquear" title="Alterar status do cadastro" oncomplete="PF('confirmacaoExclusao').show()" process="@this" update="frmPesquisa:confirmacaoExclusaoDialog">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{usuario}" target="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.usuarioSelecionado}"/>    
            </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>


    </p:dataTable>

        <p:confirmDialog header="Alterar status do cadastro"
            message="Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status do cadastro do usuário #{pesquisaUsuarioBean.usuarioSelecionado.nome}?"
            widgetVar="confirmacaoExclusao" id="confirmacaoExclusaoDialog">
            <p:button value="Não"
                onclick="PF('confirmacaoExclusao').hide(); return false;" />
            <p:commandButton value="Sim"
                oncomplete="PF('confirmacaoExclusao').hide();" action="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.excluir}" process="@this" update="frmPesquisa:usuariosTable"/>
        </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
</ui:define>
```

**UsuarioFilter.java**

```
public class UsuarioFilter implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String nome;
private String status = "Ativo";

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
}
```

**UsuariosRep.java**

```
public class UsuariosRep implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Inject
private EntityManager manager;

public Usuario guardar(Usuario usuario) {
    EntityTransaction trx = manager.getTransaction();

    trx.begin();

    usuario = manager.merge(usuario);

    trx.commit();

    return usuario;
}

public Usuario porNome(String nome) 
{
    return manager.find(Usuario.class, nome);
}

public Usuario porId(Long id)
{
    return manager.find(Usuario.class, id);
}

public List<Usuario> listaDeUsu() 
{
    return manager.createQuery("from Usuario", Usuario.class).getResultList();
}

public List<Usuario> raizes()
{
    return  manager.createQuery("from Usuario",Usuario.class).getResultList(); 
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Usuario> filtrados(UsuarioFilter filtro) {

    Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Usuario.class);

    if (filtro.getNome() != "") 
    {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("nome", filtro.getNome()));
    }

    if (filtro.getStatus().equals("Ativo") || filtro.getStatus().equals("Inativo"))
    {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", filtro.getStatus()));
    }

    // orderBy do SQL
    return criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id")).list();
}

public void remover(Usuario usuario) {
    this.manager.remove(usuario);
    EntityTransaction trx = manager.getTransaction();
    trx.begin();
    manager.flush();
    trx.commit();
}
}
```

**PesquisaUsuarioBean.java**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PesquisaUsuarioBean implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private UsuariosRep usuarios;

private UsuarioFilter filtro;

private List<Usuario> usuariosFiltrados;

private Usuario usuarioSelecionado;

@Inject
private CadastroUsuarioService cadastroUsuarioService;

public PesquisaUsuarioBean() {
    filtro = new UsuarioFilter();
}

public boolean isInativo() {
    boolean inativo = false;
    for (int x = 0;x < this.usuariosFiltrados.size(); x++)
    {
        String ContasInativas = this.usuariosFiltrados.get(x).getStatus();
        if ( ContasInativas.equals("Inativo"))
        {
            inativo = true;
        }
    }
    return inativo;
}

public void excluir() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (this.usuarioSelecionado.getStatus().equals("Ativo"))
    {
        this.usuarioSelecionado.setStatus("Inativo");
    }
    else
    {
        this.usuarioSelecionado.setStatus("Ativo");
    }
    try {
        this.cadastroUsuarioService.salvar(this.usuarioSelecionado);
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("O status do cadastro do usuário " + usuarioSelecionado.getNome() + " com o CPF : " + usuarioSelecionado.getCpf() + " foi alterado com sucesso."));
        this.pesquisar();
    } catch (NegocioException e) {
        FacesMessage mensagem = new FacesMessage(e.getMessage());
        mensagem.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        context.addMessage(null, mensagem);
    }
}

public void pesquisar() {
    usuariosFiltrados = usuarios.filtrados(filtro);
}

public List<Usuario> getUsuariosFiltrados() {
    return usuariosFiltrados;
}

public UsuariosRep getUsuarios() {
    return usuarios;
}

public UsuarioFilter getFiltro() {
    return filtro;
}

public Usuario getUsuarioSelecionado() {
    return usuarioSelecionado;
}

public void setUsuarioSelecionado(Usuario usuarioSelecionado) {
    this.usuarioSelecionado = usuarioSelecionado;
}
}
```

Agradeço qualquer opinião ou sugestão.

Answer (score 0):

Faz o seguinte.
No seu método isInativo() teste primeiro o pesquisaUsuarioBean.filtro.status
Se for "Todos" retorne o desejado senão ai sim você testa a item.